# Is this code correctly storing a value to be used later?

Tags: c, pointers, reference, memcpy

I'm fixing a bug and stumbled across code that resembles the following:

```
while (true){
    memcpy( &Key, &ptr->recKey, KEY_SIZE );
    //other code
    memcpy( ptr->recKey.id, newId, ID_SIZE );
    //other code
    memcpy( ptr, &Key, KEY_SIZE );
}
```

I can't exactly tell what the above code is doing. The intention behind the code is that Key should be saving the value of recKey so that it can be used to reinitialize ptr at the end of the loop, but I'm not sure if that is what's happening.

Doesn't assigning the address of ptr->recKey to the address of Key make it so they both have the same address? So changing recKey.id on the second line must also change Key.id, correct? Am I misunderstanding what the first line is doing?

Comment: There's no way to know without a [mcve]. I hope somewhere in that `//other code` there's a `break;`.

Comment: @FredLarson Yes, there is a break, but I'm not concerned with the while loop. I would like to know what exactly memcpy() is doing each time it is used. Sorry if that wasn't communicated well.

Comment: See [some documentation on `memcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy), then.